# RTK Query, Entity Adapter - unable to retreive data via SelectAll

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I have the following PostsSlice.js:

```
import { createSelector, createEntityAdapter } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { apiSlice } from "../../features/api/apiSlice";
import * as moment from "moment";

const postsAdapter = createEntityAdapter({
});

const initialState = postsAdapter.getInitialState();

export const postApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getPosts: builder.query({
      query: (params) => {
        return { url: "/posts", params: params };
      },
      transformResponse: (responseData) => {
        return postsAdapter.setAll(initialState, responseData);
      },
      providesTags: (result, error, arg) => [
        { type: "Post", id: "LIST" },
        ...result.ids.map((id) => ({ type: "Post", id })),
      ],
    }),
  }),
});

export const {
  useGetPostsQuery,
} = postApiSlice;

export const selectPostsResult =
  postApiSlice.endpoints.getPosts.select();

const selectPostsData = createSelector(
  selectPostsResult,
  (postsResult) => postsResult.data 
);

export const {
  selectAll: selectAllPosts,
  selectById: selectPostById,
  selectIds: selectPostIds,
} = postsAdapter.getSelectors(
  (state) => selectPostsData(state) ?? initialState
);
```

**Problem.**
I'm trying to select Posts, filtered by userId.
I'm calling `useGetPostsQuery({userId:1})` method from my App component and I see data are being fetched and stored in my "Posts" state, however, I'm unable to access the data via `useSelector(selectAllPosts)`.

When I call `useGetPostsQuery()` without arguments, I'm then able to retreive the data from state via `selectAllPosts`.

Here's the Codesandbox link to my example - https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-sanderson-588n9c?file=/src/App.js

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What happens if you add `overrideExisting: true` to the object you're passing to `injectEndpoints`?

Comment: Tried adding `overrideExisting:true` to `injectEndpoints`, but nothing changed - still no results when calling method with arguments and then selecting `SelectAllPosts`.

Answer (score 0):

```
export const selectPostsResult =
  postApiSlice.endpoints.getPosts.select();
```

in this function, you need to specify params inside `select()`, which is impossible from API place